# What's the equivalent of '[[something retain] autorelease]' in ARC?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

What's the equivalent of `[[something retain] autorelease]` in ARC?

I have a problem where a class DBRequest calls my delegate to signify completion. My delegate then sets the DBRequest instance to nil, which dealloc's it. But then when the stack pops out of my delegate and jumps back to the DBRequest, it of course then crashes.

If I wasn't in ARC, in my delegate I'd simply do `[[theDbRequest retain] autorelease]` before releasing my reference to it, so that it'd survive long enough until the next run loop autoreleased it.

What should I do in ARC?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about adding something like

```
__strong DBRequest * myself = self;
[delegate reportDone];
```

I think that'll increment the self object until the end of the function preventing it from dying early.

Comment: I *could* open the dropbox code up and do that... I was hoping there'd be a way i could do this without needing to modify their code.

Comment: @Chris, Ok, I didn't realize that bit was in their code. I'm not sure but you may be able to put a `__autoreleasing DBRequest * theDBRequest = dbRequest` in your code.

Comment: In the end, that's exactly what i did :)

Answer (score 3):

> My delegate then sets the DBRequest instance to nil, which dealloc's it. But then when the stack pops out of my delegate and jumps back to the DBRequest, it of course then crashes.

Surely this was always a bad strategy, and your `[[theDbRequest retain] autorelease]` was always just covering up the problem, yes?

Simply do nothing. So your instance variable sticks around; so what? You know that ARC will release it for you when you are dealloced.

The important thing is not to release `theDbRequest`, but to set theDbRequest's reference to *you* (the delegate) to nil, so it doesn't try to call you back when you no longer exist. Your own dealloc would be a good place to do that.

Hope I'm understanding the issue correctly. If not, post some code!

Comment: I think it's a problem caused by the dropbox api in question isn't written using ARC, so arc somehow can't figure out the ownership in question. I know that whenever you call a delegate who is likely to free yourself, it's a good idea to call 'self retain autorelease' first, but the dropbox api isn't doing that, so i have to do something. But what?

Comment: Here's something interesting too, if i don't set theDbRequest to nil, it never gets released at all (even after my delegate is released). ARC works in mysterious ways? Tempted to run back to non-arc land...

Comment: Sorry I don't know the DropBox API. Could there be a naming problem? ARC makes assumptions about how to manage memory based on the *name* of the method when we cross over from a non-ARC file to an ARC file. There's a very good WWDC 2011 video that deals with that; there are ways to work around it by adding a qualifier that tells ARC what to do.

Comment: Also, be careful in your terminology: released is not the same as dealloced. I guarantee that ARC releases a strong ivar when your delegate is dealloced. But that might not dealloc the ivar if that isn't the last reference. You might need to use a weak reference here (ARC-weak, extremely cool). But before you try that, use Instruments to work out who is retaining your delegate. And watch out for retain cycles, which can arise easily under ARC; see my book, http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html#_retain_cycles_and_weak_references

Answer (score 3):

As @matt says if you simply do nothing ARC should clean up when your object is deallocated - assigning the `DBRequest` you create to an instance variable handles that (*provided* of course your object outlasts the object you are creating).

If you need to deallocate the `DBRequest` *before* your object dies then you need an ARC-compatible "trick" equivalent to `[[theDbRequest retain] autorelease]`. Now unless you are constructing your own auto release pools your previous approach would trigger at the end of the current event. Following that logic try:

1. Add a method to your class which simply sets `theDbRequest` to `nil`, let's call this `cleanUpTheDbRequest`.
2. Change your delegate callback to invoke `[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(cleanUpTheDbRequest) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO]` instead of directly assigning `nil` to `theDbRequest`

This should delay the assigning of `nil` till after the end of the current event, just as your autorelease "trick" did. It also works if your `DBRequest` lives across multiple events - the previous method kicks in at the end of the event the `autorelease` is called in, this method at the end of the event the delegate method is called in.