# NSObject: retained, removed from array and returned with autorelease, what to do for ARC?

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

I have the following piece of code:

```
NSObject *anObject = [[objArray lastObject] retain];
[objArray removeLastObject];
return [anObject autorelease];
```

With ARC I cannot use retain or autorelease, but if I:

```
NSObject *anObject = [objArray lastObject];
[objArray removeLastObject];
return anObject;
```

isn't `anObject` reaching a 0 retain count when it is removed from array?

I found:
[What's the equivalent of '[[something retain] autorelease]' in ARC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643770/whats-the-equivalent-of-something-retain-autorelease-in-arc)
but it does look like the same situation.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, `anObject` is not released because it is still used in the `return` statement.

What ARC does is look at your code, decide where you are using each variable, and insert corresponding `retain` and `release` calls behind the hood while compiling your code into an executable.

If you want to make absolutely sure that a variable survives through a critical section (although there's *very* rarely a need for that, and certainly not here), then you can declare it explicitely as 
`__strong`. But make sure you understand what are the relationships between your objects, because you can easily create retain cycles and memory leaks by defeating the purpose of ARC.

Comment: So you are saying it should be fine with retain and autorelease removed?

Answer (score 0):

Your second block of code is fine because the local variable 'anObject' is a strong reference. This code would only be a problem if you declared 'anObject' to be a weak reference.

Comment: Do you mean `NSObject *anObject = [objArray lastObject];` will retain the last object?

Comment: Yes, ARC will take care of that for you. This is the joy of ARC. You can stop worrying about memory management in most cases. You still need to worry about retain cycles but for code like this, just have faith that the compiler will do the right thing for you. The best thing you can do it try it. Get rid of retain and autorelease, just like your second code block and run it. Take joy in the fact that it won't crash :)